# How do I fit an EditText to a Table Cell in Java during dynamic programming?

Tags: android, android-edittext, tablerow, tablecell

**Problem:** I'm having difficulty getting an EditText field to fit within a table cell dimensions.

**What I've tried:** I have tried a number of suggestions, like below in my code, stated here on StackOverflow but nearly all are static and not dynamic examples. I looked at a couple videos which were about the same.

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to give the user an option to add a row of data to a table and fill in the fields. The following code works out well except I cannot seem to find the correct way of stating the `LayoutParams` to fit the `EditText` within the cell boundaries.

```
for(int r=1; r<5;r++) {
   EditText editText = new EditText(this);
   editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
   editText.setTextSize(12);
   editText.setSingleLine();
   editText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   row.addView(editText);
}
```

[image: Table Cell EditText]

```
<TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/table_authors"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@color/colorDkGray"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_add_author"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
```

The code to setup table in the `EditNote` activity:

```
tableLayoutAuthors = findViewById(R.id.table_authors);
        tableLayoutAuthors.addView(setupAuthorsTableRow("+", "Organization/First", "Middle Name", "Last Name","Suffix", true));

btnAddAuthor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tableLayoutAuthors.addView(setupAuthorsTableRow("-","", "", "", "", false));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is your `TableLayout` in xml file or even that's added at runtime? Can you please share related the `row` & `table` xml or runtime whichever you've used?

Comment: @Mayur Gajra I added the XML, the code to setup the table, and the `onClick` events to manage the table rows. Note, the `setupAuthorsTableRow` method manages the building of the header and any add'l row the user wants to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Mayur Gajra, I was able to figure out how to fix my issue. Posted below is what fixed my issue:

Adding this line to the XML:

```
android:stretchColumns="*"
```

Changing to creating an instance of `TableRow.LayoutParams` and setting the margins and setting the padding for the `editText`:

```
    for(int r=1; r<5;r++) {
          EditText editText = new EditText(this);
 // Change:   
          TableRow.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
          trLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
          editText.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
    
          editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
          editText.setTextSize(12);
          editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
          editText.setSingleLine();

   // Change: 
          editText.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    
          row.addView(editText);
          row.setClickable(true);
      }
```

[image: Corrected Table Row with EditText]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make few adjustments:

1. In the xml `TableLayout` add `android:stretchColumns="*"` which means that stretch all columns.

   ```
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_authors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="716dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
   ```
2. You need to set `editText` width to 0. Because with `WRAP_CONTENT` it respects the content width it has to wrap & not the cell boundaries.

This is how sample code would look like:

```
TableLayout tableLayoutAuthors  = findViewById(R.id.table_authors);
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        for (int r = 1; r < 5; r++) {
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            editText.setTextSize(12);
            editText.setText("test");
            editText.setSingleLine();
            editText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            row.addView(editText);
        }
        tableLayoutAuthors .addView(row);
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion to add the stretch columns works well. but with the TableRow LayoutParams "0", I was still not getting the margins and padding to work and the EditText would still remain as my above pic in the question body. However, I stumbled on 2 fixes correcting my issue: 1) setMargins of the row layout params, and 2) setPadding of the EditText solved my issue. I posted as answer in combination with your suggestion.